# Explain handling DBNull?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, dbnull

I have a nullable DateTime field "BirthDate" the existing code was handeling this in such a way

```
info.BirthDate = (DateTime?)reader["Birthdate"];
```

This causes an "Invalid Cast" error and it breaks. Ok, I understand this is because nulls are returned differently from sql and are of the type "DBNull"

Fix for this turned out to be

```
if (reader["Birthdate"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    info.Birthdate = (DateTime)reader["Birthdate"];
}
```

Can someone explain why exactly this works?..I'm particularly lost on the .Value part of DBNull. If it *IS* returning as DBNull how does the code even reach inside this block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DBNull` is a singleton. There is only one instance of it. You access this instance with `DBNull.Value`. The comparison checks if `DBNull(.Value)` is returned and if it is not returned (`!=`) then it knows it can safely cast it to a `DateTime`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx):

> DBNull is a singleton class, which means only this instance of this
>   class can exist.

Alternatively you could use the `Convert.IsDBNull` method:

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(reader["Birthdate"]))
{
    info.Birthdate = (DateTime)reader["Birthdate"];
}
```

Comment: ....OH. Alright since the property is nullable, it remains nothing and this block is skipped. I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: A third option is `reader["Birthdate"] as DateTime?`. (There are valid objections to this third option, and there are also valid arguments in favour of it. I'd prefer to avoid that discussion. :))

Comment: Ah right, will do. Says I can in 4 mins. This is my first post to SO

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull` is a *type*, not a *value*.  As @aKzenT explained, it is implemented as a singleton, meaning there can only only be one *instance* of that type.   The way to get to that one value is through the static `.Value` property.

This makes it easy to do comparisons since any `DBNull` instance is equal in both value and reference to another `DBNull` instance.

Another way to do that check which may make more sense is:

```
int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Birthdate");
if (!reader.IsDbNull(columnIndex)) // IsDbNull should have a string overload, but it does not.
{
    info.Birthdate = (DateTime)reader["Birthdate"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification!..so glad I decided to post here instead of cluelessly  wondering.